# does javascript speech synthesis for saying a list need a callback

Tags: javascript, text-to-speech

I want to say each letter in a list of only 4 letters. My example just says "click" for each letter for now, but my code is not producing the "click". It produces one "click" when the page is loaded if the following javascript statement is supplied: `speechSynthesis.speak(msg);`. But as part of my function `next()` I get no sound.

Javascript:

```
var msg = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance();
var voices = window.speechSynthesis.getVoices();
msg.voice = voices[10]; // Note: some voices don't support altering params
msg.voiceURI = 'native';
msg.volume = 1; // 0 to 1
msg.rate = 1; // 0.1 to 10
msg.pitch = 2; //0 to 2
msg.text = 'click';
msg.lang = 'en-US';

    function next() {
      if (cardi < showdeal.length - 1) {
        var text = showdeal.substr(cardi + 1,1);
        document.getElementById("dealcardto").innerHTML = text;
        cardi++;
      speechSynthesis.speak(msg);
      }
  }
```

Html:

```
<button onclick="next()" class="button">Next in list</button>
<span style="font-size: 60" id="cardletterto">X</span>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xn09mk7c/)

Comment: You are missing any element with `id="theletter"` https://jsfiddle.net/xn09mk7c/1/ - BTW holy smokes, i had no idea that js has in built voice synth support :O - Pleasant surprises every day :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the developer tools in your browser
2. Look at the Console
3. **Read the error reports**

It says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

You changed the `id` of the span between writing the HTML and writing the JS.

The script is aborting before getting to `speechSynthesis.speak(msg);`.